# How do I display the count of one field in line with another query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've tried inner joins, cross joins and selecting on right inner joins and I can't seem to achieve what I want to show.

I have a table like so

```
Content
------------
|ID        |
|PalletID  |
|ProductID |
|DateIn    |
------------
```

I've attached an image with a sample data set and the results I'm trying to achieve. Any help is welcome as I've been stuck on this for a few hours now.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hey @Tony Hopkinson. Yeah, It's something I have to work on, so I do apologize for too all the people that take time help.

I posted this question at the end of the workday as my brain was melted. Our VPN server is down so I'll have to wait for the morning to choose an answer.

To the people that asked about the Product Name, I will have to do a join with another table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a simple `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` would work for you:

```
SELECT  DateIn, ProductID, COUNT(*) [No. Of Pallets]
FROM    Content
GROUP BY DateIn, ProductID
```

Or if you have another table that stores the product name you might need something like this:

```
SELECT  DateIn, ProdName, COUNT(*) [No. Of Pallets]
FROM    Content
        INNER JOIN Product
            ON Product.ProductID = Content.ProductID
GROUP BY DateIn, ProdName
```

Comment: As I said above, I can't check this until the morning, but this looks like it will do what I want to do. Thanks for the time you took to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a query like the following:

```
 select DateIn, ProductId, count(*) as NumPallets
 from Content
 group by DateIn, ProductId
 order by ProductId, DateIn
```

I assume that your DateIn field is really a date field (if it's not you need to convert).

You said ProductName in your drawing, but you give productId in your table definition.  I assume they are the same.  If not, then you'll need to add an extra join to resolve Id -> name.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT  DateIn, ProductID, COUNT(1) AS NoOfPallets 
FROM Content 
GROUP BY DateIn, ProductID 
ORDER By DateIn, ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `GROUP BY`?

```
select DateIn
, ProductID
, No_Of_Pallets=COUNT(*)
from Content
group by DateIn, ProductID
```